# Controlling label placement with the point displacement renderer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, geology

I work with geological map symbols that involve symbol rotation and the placement of labels relative to the orientation. A simple example is placing a label at the tip of an arrow symbol regardless of the direction it is pointing. I am able to do this using the data driven override code for placement around the centroid.

However, there are instances where the Point Displacement render is required to display closely spaced symbols.

**My problem:** the Label option in the Point Displacement dialogue does not provide a means for *symbol-oriented labelling*. If I set the Label option to None then my previous symbol-oriented labeling occurs but the labels do not shift with the symbols and overlap with each other. I can manually shift the problem labels to solve the problem for a given scale.

**The question: is there a variable stored somewhere representing the symbol positional shift that I can use to recalculate the label position?**
[image]

[image: My example shows the three symbols shifted using the point displacement tool. The labels have been manually adjusted as they overlapped each other. The other 2 symbols did not need adjusting]

My example in the upper image above shows the three symbols shifted using the point displacement tool and the problem with the label positions. In the lower image the labels have been manually adjusted with the labelling toolbar.